# how to create a temp-table for code_mstr in progress 4gl?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to create a temp-table for generalized code maintenance(code_mstr) such that the input I give in GCM does not hit the database but instead is stored in a temporary table from where I can update or delete the records. which has the fields

```
code_fldname
code_value
code_cmmt
code_group
```

I am very new to progress and this task is a little daunting as I am not understanding how to begin, I have been going through examples and syntax of temp-table, the only thing I managed to write so far is this code which Im not sure is correct or not

```
define temp-table tt_gcm no-undo
field tt_fldname like code_fldname
field tt_value like code_value
field tt_cmmt like code_cmmt
field tt_group like code_group   
field tt_domain like global_domain
index tt_idx
      tt_domain
      tt_fldname
      tt_value.
```

and after this I defined a form for the same

```
form
code_fldname
code_value
code_cmmt
code_group
with frame a side-labels
```

now suppose if I enter a particular record in code_mstr, I want only that one particular record to be visible in the temp-table rather than all the records that are in code_mstr, any help on how to proceed with that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines will fill your temp-table:

```
for each code_mstr no-lock:

  create tt_gcm.
  assign
    tt_gcm.tt_fldname = code_mstr.code_fldname
    tt_gcm.tt_value   = code_mstr.code_value
    tt_gcm.tt_cmmt    = code_mstr.code_cmmt
    tt_gcm.tt_group   = code_mstr.code_group   
    tt_gcm.tt_domain  = code_mstr.global_domain
  .

end.
```

and this will display the data in the form that you created:

```
for each tt_gcm:
  display tt_gcm with frame a.
end.
```

Comment: I kind of understand the logic here and on trying this it says code_fldname is ambiguous in the field definition of code_fldname that I mentioned above. is it getting confused as to from where I am calling the code_fldname from code_mstr or from tt_gcm

Comment: I had assumed that the field names were unique due to the "tt_" prefix but you can fully qualify a fieldname by adding the tablename, like code_mstr.code_fldname and tt_gcm.tt_fldname.  (If you have multiple connected databases that have duplicate table names you can also add dbname.tablename.fieldname.)

Comment: yes i did that, it solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: is there any way to display specific records from code_mstr, like currently, your solution displays all the records that are present. what if I give a prompt-for for code_fldname and then I only want to display records that I enter through code_fldname. is that possible?

Comment: Sure, but you're getting into "new question" territory ;) You might want to mark this one as "correct", upvote the answer if you are pleased with it, and then open a new question.

Comment: oh yes sorry almost got carried away I accepted the answer but it won't let me upvote because of less reputation

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep your temp-table field names the same as your database field names, you can use the `buffer-copy` statement. It will copy all matching fields from one to the other.

```
define temp-table tt_gcm no-undo
  field global_domain like code_mstr.global_domain
  field code_fldname like code_mstr.code_fldname
  field code_value like code_mstr.code_value

  field code_cmmt like code_mstr.code_cmmt
  field code_group like code_mstr.code_group   

  index tt_idx // add is unique?
    global_domain
    code_fldname
    code_value
  .

for each code_mstr no-lock:

  create tt_gcm.
  buffer-copy code_mstr to tt_gcm.

end.
```